# cleaning out sequence with only desired bases?

Tags: python

I have a FastA file, and for the output I only want the sequence from the file to print. I have that down, but I also only want certain letters to be printed from that sequence - (A,C,T,G,N, and U). Could someone give me an outline to show me how to do this as a for loop, by any chance? This is what I had attempted under my "clean sequence" method, but I think the format is off. nucParams is my class.:

```
clean = ''
        for aa in self.fastAsequence:
            if letter in nucParams.base_list:
                clean += letter
                self.clean = clean
            print(self.clean)
```

And here is the list I placed in to my **init** portion of the code:

base_list = ("A", "C", "T", "G", "N", "U")

Comment: What problem do you get?

Comment: I get "global name 'letter' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `letter`. Probably:

```
for letter in self.fastAsequence:
```

However note that:

```
clean += letter
```

will become exponentially slow the longer self.fastAsequence is. So you may want to gather the letters into an array, and then do a `join` at the end.

Also printing out `clean` every time through the loop will slow things up and produce a lot of output.

Comment: so gathering the letters before joining them would make it less laggy? Could you give me an idea of how the format of that could look?